# SSL3 Certificate Verify Failed when Connecting to JIRA API Using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm currently running into an error when attempting to connect to JIRA using Python2.7 and the JIRA REST API (http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

When I execute the following:

```
from jira.client import JIRA

options = {
    'server': 'https://jira.companyname.com'
}
jira = JIRA(options)
```

I get the following error message in console:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Is there something that I may have missed or am doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly your Jira server's SSL certificate is signed by a non-standard CA, that is trusted by your browser but not by the SSL library Python is using.

Comment: In your options add
'verify': False
to not check the certificate

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*I know I'm late on this answer, but hopefully this helps someone down the road.*

---

**Why you shouldn't turn off verification**

While turning off certificate verification is the easiest "solution", it is
not an advisable thing to do. It essentially says,
"I don't care if I trust you or not, I'm going to send you all my information anyway."
This opens you up for a Man-in-the-Middle attack.

If you're connecting to your company's Jira server and it has a
certificate for TLS/SSL, you should be verifying against that.
I'd ask your IT department where that certificate is. It's probably
in some root certificate for your company.

If you're connecting to the server in Chrome (for example)
it should show a lock in the left-hand corner of address bar if it's secured
over TLS/SSL.

You can `Right-Click that lock -> Details -> View Certificate` in Chrome.

**Okay, so what do I do?**

Provide the necessary certificate to the `verify` option directly.

`jira-python` uses `Requests` for HTTP stuff [(See documentation)](https://pythonhosted.org/jira/index.html?highlight=requests#requests).
And according to [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)
you can specify a path to a certificate file in `verify`.

Thus, you can provide the root certificate for your company in `verify` like so:

```
jira_options = {
    'server': jira_server_name,
    'verify': 'path/to/company/root/certificate',
}
```

If you're using a Windows machine (a safe assumption?), that root
certificate is stored in the registry and the best way to get it
is using [`wincertstore`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wincertstore).

Comment: Just a note that if the problem being worked around is a misconfigured JIRA server that is only sending the leaf certificate back to the client and not the entire cert chain, then the verification bundle will need to contain the intermediate cert(s) as well as the root cert. This can be in PEM format

Answer (score 15):

I encountered a similar SSL certificate verification error and looking through the "JIRA" methods definitions, its possible to turn off the verification.

```
    :param options: Specify the server and properties this client will use. Use a dict with any
     of the following properties:
      * server -- the server address and context path to use. Defaults to ``http://localhost:2990/jira``.
      * rest_path -- the root REST path to use. Defaults to ``api``, where the JIRA REST resources live.
      * rest_api_version -- the version of the REST resources under rest_path to use. Defaults to ``2``.
      * verify -- Verify SSL certs. Defaults to ``True``.
      * resilient -- If it should just retry recoverable errors. Defaults to `False`.
```

Try this :

```
from jira.client import JIRA

options = {'server': 'https://jira.companyname.com','verify':False}
jira = JIRA(options)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You just saved my Bacon

Comment: Unfortunately this will trigger a warning: `InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made.`

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I thought I'd add this here. Ignoring those warnings can be dangerous. It essentially says, "I don't care if I trust you or not, I'm going to send you all my information anyway." You may think you're communicating with a specific server, but have no proof that it's really that server unless you've verified it.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows system please do the following:-

1. Go to the website using google chrome, then click on Lock button.
2. Now click on **certificate**, a new window pops up.
3. Next click on **Certification Path**, select first option from list which will be root, then select **View Certificate**, another window pops up.
4. Go to **Details** tab, click on **Copy To File**. Then click on **Next**, select **Base-64 encoded x509.(CER)** radio button, click on Next and save the .cer file locally.

Once the .cer file is obtained, add it to the python script as follows:-

```
jira_options = {
    'server': jira_server_name,
    'verify': 'path_to_directory_containing_certificate_file/certificate.cer'
}
```

This should work without any security warnings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I tried this and obtained the .cer file but when I try connection with this certificate path, I get below warning :
WARNING:root:Got ConnectionError [HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))] errno:None on GET
Would appreciate any thoughts on what goes wrong ?
I am running Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10

Comment: @MohammedRaqeeb, can you let me know what path value you are passing to verify key?

Comment: Hi @sattva_venu, I tried the 3 variations listed below and I get the same error with all of them:
'verify': 'D:\JiraLogger\JiraCert.cer'
'verify': 'D:\\JiraLogger\\JiraCert.cer'
'verify': 'D:/JiraLogger/JiraCert.cer'

Comment: @MohammedRaqeeb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497457/python-cant-connect-jira-api-via

Answer (score 4):

Just install python-certifi-win32 module, and this should help you get past these errors without any more hassle

Comment: Worked great for me! Thanks for posting this alternative, it saved me a lot of problems :)

Comment: `python-certifi-win32` has been [replaced](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/issues/16) by [`pip-system-certs`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/).