# Python Can't connect Jira API via

Tags: python-3.x, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to connect jira's API via python (3.6) and i keep getting error message:

> WARNING:root:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /secure/rest/api/2/serverInfo/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)) while doing GET https://jira/secure/rest/api/2/serverInfo/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{'params': None, 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.20.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'}}]
> WARNING:root:Got ConnectionError [HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /secure/rest/api/2/serverInfo/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))] errno:None on GET https://jira/secure/rest/api/2/serverInfo/rest/api/2/serverInfo
> {'response': None, 'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>}{'response': None, 'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>}
> WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET https://jira/secure/rest/api/2/serverInfo/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 7.466325591185807s. Err: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /secure/rest/api/2/serverInfo/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

This is my code:

```
un='myusername'
pwd='mypassword'
server='https://jira/xxxx'

jira = jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(un, pwd), options={'server': server})
issue = jira.issue('some issue name')

print(issue.fields.project.key)
print(issue.fields.issuetype.name)
```

When using curl to the same server everything works good.

Comment: Bad SSL handshake tells you that the verification of the SSL certificate failed..

Comment: Thanks For aswering, I've noticed that but i'm using the verification with CURL and it's ok, just with JIRA MODULE via Python it's giving that error... any ideas?

Comment: You could provide the necessary certificate to the verify option as stated in my answer below..

Comment: Any success or do you have additional questions regarding that topic?

Comment: Still the same error message, I saved the jira cert to file and added your line,it's really strange because we when i use "Requests" i'm able to connect.

Comment: Have you tried what i suggested in my **EDIT**?

Comment: Strange.. This is definitly not recommended - but what happens when you try `'verify':false`?

Comment: And on a additional note: can you update/edit your question with the code you are currently using as well as the error-msg in case it differs from the recent one

Comment: Worked! in false mode it's good,thanks a lot!

Comment: NP - it's my pleasure. I'll add that to my answer - If it helped you may [accept and upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can provide the necessary certificate to the `verify` option.

`jira-python` uses `Requests` for HTTP[(docs)](https://pythonhosted.org/jira/index.html?highlight=requests#requests).

According to [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)
you can specify a path to a certificate file in `verify`.
So you can provide the root certificate in `verify` like so:

```
jira_options = {
   'server': jira_server_name,
   'verify': 'path/to/root/certificate',
}
```

So in your case just change to this:

```
jira = jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(un, pwd), options={'server': server,'verify': 'path/to/root/certificate',})
```

In Chrome for example you can show the certificate as described in this [article](https://medium.com/rapidsslonline/quick-steps-to-view-ssl-certificate-in-google-chrome-60a02f0e92f5)

**EDIT:**

Connect to your server in Chrome and click on the lock shown in the left-hand corner of address bar and right-click that lock (see image below), then click 'details', then 'view certificate'. Then save this cert to file and refer to it in `verify`.

[image: lock]

Another way, as @Snow mentioned in the comments below, is to open the development-tools via `F12` and then navigate to the Security tab.

From the docs:

**SSL CERT VERIFICATION:**

> If verify is set to a path to a directory, the directory must have been processed using the c_rehash utility supplied with OpenSSL.

**CLIENT SIDE CERTIFICATES:**

> The private key to your local certificate must be unencrypted. Currently, Requests does not support using encrypted keys.

There's also the option to set `'verify':false` - thou it's not recommended since turning off certificate verification leaves you vulnerable for [Man-in-the-Middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: I can't find this Lock button you mention. Where is it exactly?

Comment: @Snow I added an image to my answer that should clarify the location of said lock in the address-bar..

Comment: thank you, I managed to get it via Developer tools --> Security tab. Although yours looks quicker.

Comment: @Snow Yeah - dev-tools via `F12` works as well, but right-clicking the lock is just one or two steps faster ;) Thx for the comment -  let me add your way to my answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just by installing "python-certifi-win32", the SSL error is cleared for me. I didn't provide any certificates or anything.